# generate month names based on entries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table in mysql

```
  ID    From_Year  From_Month  To_Year    To_Month    int
  1     2011        4          2012            3        8    
  2     2012        4          2013            3       8.6   
  3     2013        4          2014            3       8     
  4     2014        4          2014            8       8     
  5     2014        9          2015            3       8
```

can get sequential month name from each record means
for ID 1 i will get April to Dec and Jan to March  Name

**EDIT**
end result will look like for ID =1

```
 **month name**
   April
   May
   Jun
    .
    .
   Dec
  Jan
   Feb
   Mar
```

if less than 1 year only that month enclosed should generate in serial

Comment: how to result looks like, if you can put the exact result

Comment: And what if there are more than 1 years?

Comment: Change your datamodel to use a proper `DateTime` object instead of several integers then use `MONTH(datetime_colum)` in combination with a switch or maybe with some `FORMAT` using the appropriate locale.

Comment: Write your expected result

Comment: @jmail   edited question for result

Answer (score 0):

```
select MONTHNAME(MAKEDATE(YEAR(now()), 1) + INTERVAL From_Month MONTH) 
from the_table
```